# Wordpress Font Awesome Icons CSS Padding Issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have trawled the internet looking for a fix and i still cannot get padding to work on my FA Icons in a wordpress theme.

Caution, I am novice:

So, the icons are social media icons, using FA, and they are placed in a widget in the footer of the site.

I think i have assigned a class to the icons "social" but I have placed:

```
.social {
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

In all style.css or custom.css or theme related .css's I can find and the icons still only have around 3px of padding, widget code is as follows:

```
<p>
<a target="_blank" href="link"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-4x" class="social"></i></a>
<a target="_blank" href="link"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x" class="social"></i></a>
<a target="_blank" href="link"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x" class="social"></i></a>
<a target="_blank" href="link"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-square fa-4x" class="social"></i></a>
</p>
```

I'm sure I am missing something simple?

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: Have you tried setting your li to inline-block? `.social { padding-left: 20px; display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `social` class to the same attribute:

```
<i class="fa fa-pinterest-square fa-4x social"></i>
```

Change the css property to:

```
.social {
    padding-left:20px !important;
}
```

Please note that the css properties are assigned in the order they were defined in the css files. You must be sure that the `.social` is the last defined, in order to assign the `padding-left` you need.